# Как писать на dart в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dart

Хочу писать на dart, но многие нужные мне sdk написаны на javascript. Нужна возможность их использования из dart, или компиляция dart в javascript, для интеграции в node.js. У кого есть такой опыт? Может гдето есть мануал как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В node.js невозможно писать на Dart: потому что node.js это среда выполнения (интерпретатор и доп. библиотеки), а не текстовый редактор.

Возможность использования из кода Dart различных JS SDK (т.е., возможность выполнения произвольного кода на JavaScript) - может обеспечить пакет [**js**](https://pub.dev/packages/js).
Документация у этого пакета - [есть](https://pub.dev/documentation/js/latest/), хоть и краткая.

Компиляция Dart в JavaScript - тоже возможна: либо с помощью уже упомянутого пакета [**js**](https://pub.dev/packages/js), либо прямыми вызовами инструментов [`dartdevc`](https://dart.dev/tools/dartdevc) или [`dart2js`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js) (они оба содержатся в Dart SDK).

Comment: Я смог настроить компиляцию dart->javascript при помощи dart2js и запуск готового js в node.js. Но как вызывать javascript библиотеки из dart, по прежнему не понятно. В справке пакета js есть пример только использования в браузере (и я его не смог запустить). Мне же нужно консольное приложение dart с вызовом сторонних библиотек javascript

Comment: @iLnar, в _консольном_ приложении, вряд ли получится использовать JS из Dart - единственным вариантом для CLI приложений на дарте, я вижу внешние вызовы `npx` (использование js-библиотек как внешних, неуправляемых зависимостей).

Comment: @iLnar, в общем и целом, не совсем понятно: при том что нода в любом случае используется (ради js-библиотек), зачем тогда вообще использовать Dart... ведь значительно разумнее будет написать CLI-приложение полностью на JS, и при его выполнении гонять только одну виртмашину вместо двух (заодно, примерно втрое сократив сложность поддержки кодовой базы проекта). Вот если бы не стояло условие юзать js-библиотеки, в использовании Dart был бы смысл. А так... странное решение.

Comment: Почему две виртуальные машины? Dart компилируется в javascript на этапе разработки. И вроде бы сгенерированный код работает даже быстрее написанного вручную. Я в javascript почти не имею опыта. После dart он кажется сущим адом. К тому же большая часть кода приложения уже написана на dart. Но стали нужны вызовы сторонних библиотек на javascript. Просто так было бы быстрее

Comment: @iLnar, _«Почему две виртуальные машины?»_ - потому что использование node + Dart подразумевает работу VM ноды + Dart VM, разве не очевидно? То, чего тебе хотелось изначально, это неэффективный сценарий использования: потому что в нем обе технологии работают "параллельно", при том что в написании CLI приложений они взаимозаменяемы (все что может одна, может и другая). Но к этому сценарию **не** относится случай _«Dart компилируется в javascript»_, т.к. это то же самое, что написать приложение полностью на JS.